# i have two types of users in my flutter and firebase application

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

Some of the users are added manually in firebase DB. those can only do the signIn and they will be directed to a specific widgets and the others are able to do the signUp and SignIn and directed automatically to the home page.

the UI widgets are done.